# Почему выдаёт конфликт размеров операндов?

Tags: ассемблер

```
_asm
    {
        mov edx,a
        mov ecx,x
        mul x
        mul x
        mul b
        mov p1,ecx
        imul edx,edx
        mul c
        mov p2,edx
        mov eax,a
        move ebx,d
        sub ebx,eax
        mov p3,ebx
        idiv p2,p3
        mov ebx,10
        mov eax,x
        sub ebx,eax
        mul 8
        mov p4,ebx
        mov eax,p1
        add eax,p2
        sub eax,p4
        mov y,eax
}
```

Comment: вероятно у вас переменные других размеров нежели регистры. А объявления переменных то вы и не показали ...

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите число x";
 double x, a, b, c, d, f, p1, p2, p3, p4, y;
 cin >> x;
 a = tan(x);
 b = 3;
 c = 4;
 d = 5;
 f = 8;
 _asm
 {
  mov edx,a
  mov ecx,x
  mul x
  mul x
  mul b
  mov p1,ecx
  imul edx,edx
  mul c
  mov p2,edx
  mov eax,a
  move ebx,d
  sub ebx,eax
  mov p3,ebx
  idiv p2,p3
  mov ebx,10
  mov eax,x
  sub ebx,eax
  mul 8
  mov p4,ebx
  mov eax,p1
  add eax,p2
  sub eax,p4
  mov y,eax
 }
 cout << y;
 return 0;
}

Comment: не могли бы вы мне наглядно показать что не так

Comment: Вставляйте код в вопрос, а не в комментарии. Под сообщением есть ссылка "править".

Comment: Ну можно сказать что все не так. У вас почти все переменные double - это числа с плавающей точкой. А используемые в ассемблерном коде инструкции - все целочисленные, т.е. предназначенные для работы с целыми числами. Единственный тип данных который помещается в используемые во вставке регистры - это целочисленный 32 битный. Т.е. скорее всего `int` (зависит от платформы и компилятора)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Ваш совет помог мне многое прояснить. Спасибо, что уделили мне время. Где бы вы ни были, будьте здоровы!